# Method invoked when app is brought back from springboard

Tags: iphone

I need the following behaviour:

An user leaves my app in the "in-app-setting" view with a tap on home-button. Then he/she does some changes in the iphone setting view and open my app again. Which method do I need to add my code in order to update the UI in the "in-app-setting" view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally, it's not a good idea to be able to edit the same settings via your app and via the built in settings view. It may confuse users and is just a duplication of the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your resume code in the `- (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` or `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` function in your app delegate .m file.  when your application starts up again after the user hits the home button, this function will be called

apple's documentation explains in more detail as to which function to use for certain tasks:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called as part of  transition from the background to the active state: here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
    Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
         */
}
```

viewWillAppear doesn't get called because when the app is in the background/suspended, the view still exists.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of checking the reference for the UIApplication Delegate.