# What method is invoked when user comes back from springboard after launching a modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542310/method-invoked-when-app-is-brought-back-from-springboard), with one exception. Instead of having a normal navigation controller launching my default view controller, I've added an additional view controller that is simply a splash page that allows me to show a loading dialog / etc

In my "viewDidLoad" of the main view controller I launch this using "presentModalViewController" like so

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    SplashPage *splashScreen = [[[SplashPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashPage" bundle:nil viewControllerObj:self] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:splashScreen animated:NO]; 

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Then inside my splash view I do a few things (the first is a basic connectivity check to ensure the app has internet access for example).

And the first time the app is launched I do this check inside the viewDidLoad of the now active splash view controller (like so)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.viewController invokeConnectivityCheck];
}
```

The problem is this- when this fails and the user is "stuck" at a loading screen pre-launch (basically) what method is invoked in this splash view controller when they come back from the springboard (multitasking supported here)?

I've tried the following but each did not fire when I close the app and come back

- applicationWillEnterForeground
- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
- applicationDidBecomeActive

What am I missing here that is iOS5 friendly? Or does the main/default view controller get invoked instead of the splash because of the modal approach I'm using here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`appliationDidBecomeActive` will certainly be called when you are "coming back from the springboard".

Docs:

> This method is called to let your application know that it moved from
>   the inactive to active state. This can occur because your application
>   was launched by the user or the system. Applications can also return
>   to the active state if the user chooses to ignore an interruption
>   (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) that sent the
>   application temporarily to the inactive state.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the pattern I was using didn't lend itself to the navigation controller driven (via appDelegate) style iPhone app so instead of having the default/main view controller handle this modal in the viewDidLoad method I pushed this logic off to the appDelegate itself so it's not a responsibility of each view controller directly.

If you plan to do something like this I invoke this inside the appDelegates ? method using the currently active view controller (basically I keep state in the appDelegate so it's aware of the view controller in focus)

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    SplashPage *splashScreen = [[[SplashPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashPage" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [[self activieViewController] presentModalViewController:splashScreen animated:NO];

    ConnectivityWebService* service = [[[ConnectivityWebService alloc] initWithAppDelegate:self] autorelease];
    [service verifyConnectivity];
}
```

The other requirement of this is a call back in the appDelegate to close the modal like so

```
- (void)callBackAfterConnectivityCheck
{
    [[self activieViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Hope this was helpful to someone else (not that it directly answered the question) -if someone has a legit answer I'll give credit for that as this was mostly for history / another take on the pattern used.